# remove the outer double quotes for a string (as to convert it to an array)

Tags: javascript, string

I am working with javascript and i am struck at a point. I am getting a value from a hidden field to js:

```
<input type="hidden" value='<%= value%>' id="value1"/>
```

javascript:

```
var getValue = document.getElementById('value1').value;
```

here i get the value as : `"["1","2"]"`.

Instead of a string, i want it as an array here just by removing the outer double quotes so that i can directly use that as an array here. So i want the output like : `["1","2"]`(just removing the outer double quotes which represents its a string). Can anyone suggest how to get that?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: perfect! such a simple thing didnt strike to my mind. Sorry and thans for your time. @Barmar

Comment: @Barmar, you really should make that an answer that can be upvoted and accepted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON.parse(getValue) to parse the string into a javascript object.

```js
var getValue = '["1","2"]';
var obj = JSON.parse(getValue) //obj is now ["1", "2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [1,2];
var stringifiedArray = JSON.stringify(arr);
console.log(stringifiedArray);
var parsedArray = JSON.parse(stringifiedArray);
console.log(parsedArray);
```

Here the first one is string whereas the second one is parsed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the value is JSON, so use `JSON.parse()`.

```
var getValue = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('value1').value);
```